# Format a code block in any language using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, code-formatting

I have code blocks that are fetched from a database, which could be any language: JSON, TypeScript, JavaScript, HTML, CSS, etc.

```
snippets.each(x => {
  x.code //<-- want to apply a simple indention/formatting here
})
```

All the text comes with a broken indent/formatting that going to be used as code snippets. Here are some examples:

HTML

```
<main role="main" class="container">
<p style="margin-bottom: 2rem;">
<a href>text</a>
</p>
</main>
```

JS:

```
function example1(el: HTMLInputElement) {
if(x) {
//...
}
return el;
}
```

I want to indent all the code blocks like that so they look readable. For example:

HTML

```
<main role="main" class="container">
    <p style="margin-bottom: 2rem;">
        <a href>text</a>
    </p>
</main>
```

JS:

```
function example1(el: HTMLInputElement) {
    if(x) {
        // ...
    }
    return el;
}
```

I searched for a solution using Prettier or ESLint but haven't found yet how to use any of these just for such a simple use case.

The code block language could be unknown, so it must work regardless of language.

Comment: You might want to look at the [Prettier API](https://prettier.io/docs/en/api.html), although I don't think it can auto-detect languages.

Comment: @MichaelM. I saw that but it accepts parser name. Parser = Language, right? In my case the language is undefined. So I don't think I can figure out which one to choose https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#parser , unless I have some soft of language detector, but I don't think I want to go that far

Comment: I don't see how you can expect to reliably format code without detecting its language. Python has significant whitespace. Vb uses keywords instead of braces. How do you expect to handle _any_ language?

Comment: @CollinD right, some of the items has the language, but some don't, so may be I can use the available language prop and for these that are not defined I can fall back to something or just skip them

Comment: You’d need to parse text as every single language in existence then try to guess which one it is before even beginning to think about the indentation problem. This is way too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by combining [vscode-languagedetection](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-languagedetection) and the [Prettier API](https://prettier.io/docs/en/api.html).

vscode-languagedetection uses different programming language names than Prettier (ex: 'js' vs 'babel'), so you need to keep an conversion table `langs`. For example, vscode-languagedetection calls JavaScript "js", but Prettier calls it "babel". For every language you expect to use, you should add a conversion from the vscode-languagedetection name to the Prettier name.

```
const prettier = require("prettier");
const { ModelOperations } = require('@vscode/vscode-languagedetection');

const model = new ModelOperations();

async function formatCode(code) {
    const langPreds = await model.runModel(code);
    const lang = langPreds[0].languageId;
    const langs = {js: 'babel', html: 'html'}; // edit to convert vscode names to prettier parsers
    return prettier.format(code, { semi: false, parser: langs[lang] });
}


(async () => {
    const html = `
    <div role="main" class="container">
    <p style="margin-bottom: 2rem;">
    <a href>text</a>
    </p>
    </div>
    `;

    const js = `
    function example1(el: HTMLInputElement) {
    if(x) {
    console.log('test')
    }
    return el;
    }
    `;
    
    console.log(await formatCode(html));
    console.log(await formatCode(js));
})()
```

Output:

```
<div role="main" class="container">
  <p style="margin-bottom: 2rem">
    <a href>text</a>
  </p>
</div>

function example1(el: HTMLInputElement) {
  if (x) {
    console.log("test")
  }
  return el
}
```

If the the code block has escaped characters in it, you should unescape the code block before passing it to the function. This way, vs-languagedetection won't get confused. Once the code block has been formatted, it is OK to re-escape it.

Comment: say if your code has escape symbols like that `export class MyClass extends AnotherClass&amp;lt;ClassType&amp;gt; {` what would be the best way to solve that, is there an option within prettier or should I just decode my string manually say using https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities?

Comment: @sreginogemoh You should use html-entities to decode before passing it to the function, otherwise vscode-languagedetection wouldn't be able to detect the language.